# Correct way to use wirunsql & WiSumInf to create multiple installer

Tags: c#, windows-installer

Let me explain my scenario, because it's complex!
From Visual Studio 2019 I produce a MSI installer that install a Windows Forms application on the user PC. This installer has only one Custom Action defined, that runs during Uninstall phase from the control panel (this custom action execute a command to remove a Windows Service). This MSI installer runs good, without any problem. I can install the application, it runs well, and when I uninstall it the custom action is executed and my Windows Service is removed from the operating system. Ok!

Now I need to install multiple instances of this application, so I use the Windows Installer SDK to create many (four at the moment) MSI files. Suppose that my base installer is called App.msi; using a batch file a create App_01.msi, App_02.msi, App_03.msi and App_04.msi.
Each installer is then modified with this script:

cscript wirunsql.vbs App_01.msi "UPDATE Property SET Value='{BB0E2A06-A974-4416-A2B3-EE883A9BAE2D}' WHERE Property='ProductCode'"
cscript wirunsql.vbs App_01.msi "UPDATE Property SET Value='App 1' WHERE Property='ProductName'"
cscript wirunsql.vbs App_01.msi "UPDATE Shortcut SET Name='App 1'"
cscript WiSumInf.vbs App_01.msi 9={8D6AE98C-0C35-4283-87B9-E20263A3F9C5}
cscript WiSumInf.vbs App_01.msi 2="App 1"

The code above is only a snippet of my actual batch file, and it modify only the App_01.msi.
Now I can successfully run four installers, and I can install four instances of my Windows Forms application, obviously in four different folders.

Finally, the problem: the Uninstall custom action runs only when I uninstall the last instances of my application, regardless of the installation order. My issue is also described in this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d48d44a4-3deb-4753-94f8-a94503510a06/uninstall-event-not-working-for-multiple-instance-in-windows-installer?forum=winformssetup. But I'm not able to find a fix; maybe I'm wrong during the creation of multiple MSI?

Whats' the reason? Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: the script above is badly formatted, sorry for that.

Comment: Each cscript command performs a SQL statement inside the MSI database to update some important information of the installer: product code, product name, shortcut, and so on. Maybe am I missing other information?

Comment: I want that each installer is different from the other, so I can able to install/uninstall each MSI including the Uninstall custom action.

Comment: It seems to me that if you're getting four different products showing up as installed then the SQL to update them is not the issue. The issue seems to be in the uninstall custom action and any condition that may be surrounding that.

With that being said, I think what you may be seeing is that each install is reference counting. Each install is installing the same service with the same Component GUID. It's hard to say without more definition of what your custom action is doing. Have you logged the uninstall to confirm that the action is only running on the last one?